# Where to access archived items/lists given this layout

Tags: information-architecture, page-layout

I have an application layout with no side navigation. It just has a horizontal navigation with 5 tabs (some are greyed out). Each tab is really it's own module.

I have a todos module where a user can create lists and each list has todos.

Now I'm thinking about when a user is done with all the todos in a list, they should be able to archive that list to get it out of the way.

How could the user get to the archived list? Below is where I am now

[image]

I see these purple spaces available

[image]

The left and right are decent spaces to use, but then I need to move them somewhere else on mobile (not enough room horizontally).

The top space above the todo lists isn't bad, and will collapse down easier on mobile.

I know at the end of the day, user testing will give me the most definitive answer, at this point I'm just trying to make my "first guess" an educated one.

Any thoughts/examples on this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here. The first solution that jumps out at me is placing a `Show Archived Lists` link underneath the last list on the screen. While this approach is clean, I could see it potentially being problematic in terms of discoverability for users with a lot of lists.

This can be easily solved with a quick guerilla usability test. Create a prototype with a few lists in place and ask your testers to view archived lists. Take that feedback and iterate from there.